# What is wrong with my BMI Calculator?

Tags: java, class, methods, calculator

I am trying to make a BMI calculator that calls a method of a separate class to calculate the bmi, then continue in the main method. Below is my source code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testBMI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name;
        double bmi;
        String bmiClass;
        char z;

        Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in);

        do
        {   
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        name = readinput.nextLine();

        BMI.calculateBMI();

        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
            bmiClass = "(Underweight)";
        }
        else
            if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 25)
            {
                bmiClass = "(Normal)";
            }
            else
                if (bmi > 25.0 && bmi <= 30.0)
                {
                    bmiClass = "(Overweight)";
                }
                else
                    bmiClass = "(Obese)";

        System.out.println(name + ", your BMI is " +bmi+ "" +bmiClass+ ".");    
        System.out.print("Type Y or y to continue, or any other key to quit: ");
        z = readinput.next().charAt(0);
        } while (z == 'Y' || z == 'y');
    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI
{

    public static void calculateBMI()
    {

        Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in);

        double weight;
        double height;
        double newWeight;
        double newHeight;
        double bmi;

        System.out.print("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
        weight = readinput.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter your height in inches: ");
        height = readinput.nextInt();

        newWeight = weight * 0.45359237;

        newHeight = height * 0.0254;

        bmi = newWeight/(newHeight*newHeight);

    }
}
```

When compiling these files I successfully compile my method class ( the second snippet ) but get 1 error on the first, which reads like this:

```
testBMI.java:21: error: variable bmi might not have been initialized
        if (bmi < 18.5)
            ^
1 error
```

The variable bmi is obviously declared, but the initialization (actual value adding to the variable) occurs within the separate method, however, I'm not sure why the main method hasn't recognized it's initialization from the running of the second method. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You did not return the bmi from your BMI.calculateBMI() function.

Comment: The scope of `bmi` is local to both the main and calculateBMI method. In main method, you have not initialized the value of bmi and that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: You're also opening a duplicate scanner in your second class, and this will get your input out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value of bmi in your BMI class. When you check the value of bmi in your testBMI class it's only been locally initialized in your BMI class, not your testBMI class.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes

1. From `public static void calculateBMI()`
to `public static double calculateBMI()`

2. From `bmi = newWeight/(newHeight*newHeight);`
to `return newWeight/(newHeight*newHeight);`

3. From `BMI.calculateBMI();` 

to `bmi = BMI.calculateBMI();`

Answer (score 0):

Your `public static void calculateBMI()` method should be `public static double calculateBMI()` and return `bmi` variable.

Next in your `main` method, when calling `BMI.calculateBMI()` you should assigned returned value to `bmi` variable.

Rest of your code looks ok.

The problem you are encountering here is **scope** of variable. The `main` method has no knowledge about `bmi` variable from `BMI` class as this variable (even named same as variable in `main` class) is local.

Also you receive warning, because you **declared** `bmi` variable, but not **initialized** it. At the moment when you try to check statement `if (bmi < 18.5)` your program "doesn't know" what the value of `bmi` is.